# How do I assign a value to input-box? using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

*How do I add a value to input-box? I'm using Firefox.*

*HTML*

```
<input name="dgAgentFirstPass$ctl02$txtQuantity" id="dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity" class="inputbox" onkeypress="keyInputForPhone();" style="width:50px;text-align: right" type="text">
```

*I have tried the following JS Function and it doesn't seem to add the value*

```
function CycleCount(){
        document.getElementById("dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity").value = 1;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x30f2rf1/8/

Comment: No problem with the code.

Comment: on key press you are calling this onkeypress="keyInputForPhone();", where are you calling CycleCount()?? Are you able to get inside the method?

Comment: I don't have access to that @Jayanth I'm just trying to add values to long list of input box on inventory site using Firefox add-ons

Comment: how about window.onload = function(){
       document.getElementById("dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity").value = 1;
      }...does this work for you??

Comment: The js Function that you've defined is `CycleCount()` and the Function that you're calling `onkeypress` is `keyInputForPhone()`

Comment: Okay. I'll fix it for you but first, tell me What you exactly want to do with this code, what are you expecting

Comment: @0m3r, try giving <input name="dgAgentFirstPass$ctl02$txtQuantity" id="dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity" class="inputbox" onkeypress="CycleCount();" style="width:50px;text-align: right" type="text">

Comment: so, when you click a button you want the input to be filled with value 1?

Comment: Exactly- that’s all I’m trying to do @zainulabdeen

Comment: But when you say button, you mean a html button created on screen. right ?

Comment: let me know the `id` or `class` of that button. Hope you know How to use developer tools to get the `id` or `class` of an element

Comment: @0m3r Please see my answer below. This is exactly what you want you just have to know your button id or class and put it in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity").value=1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity">
  <button type="button" id="btn">Button</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

know your button id and change it in the script below on first line i.e `btn`

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity").value = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works okay - you just need to wait until the DOM has loaded:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script>
      function CycleCount(){
        document.getElementById("dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity").value = 1;
      } 
      window.onload = function(){
        CycleCount(); 
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input name="dgAgentFirstPass$ctl02$txtQuantity" type="text" id="dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity" class="inputbox" onkeypress="keyInputForPhone();" style="width:50px;text-align: right" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Okay the issue was `frameset` on main `index.html`*

---

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Page</title>   
</head>

<frameset cols="250,*">
    <frame src="left.html" name="LEFTFRAME">
    <frame src="right.html" name="RIGHTFRAME">
</frameset>

</html>
```

---

*left.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Left</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    Left Frame
  </body>

</html>
```

---

*right.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Right</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    Right Frame
    <br>

    <input name="dgAgentFirstPass$ctl02$txtQuantity" id="dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity" class="inputbox" style="width:50px;text-align: right" type="text">

  </body>

</html>
```

---

*JS Function*

```
function CycleCount(){
        document.getElementsByName("RIGHTFRAME")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("dgAgentFirstPass_ctl02_txtQuantity").value = 1;
    }
```